# classically is there any application of vector that can not be solved by geometric or algebraic concepts

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors

I am trying to find the classical application of vector where the problem can be solved only by vector multiplication concept and not by any other geometric or algebraic method.

for example: volume of Parallelepiped (A x B).C, but this can be simply found by algebraic calculations of edges. Why do we need to use vectors?
similarly i can find magnitude of angular momentum without using vectors and directions can be found by some set rules.

where does scalar and vector multiplication apply exclusively? what are such classical problems that can not be solved without vectors.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find the classical application of vector where the problem can be solved only by vector multiplication concept and not by any other geometric or algebraic method.

Since vectors can be expressed in co-ordinate form as algebraic objects and vector addition and multiplication can be reduced to algebraic operations on these co-ordinates then any method that uses vectors can be replaced by a purely algebraic method.

However, using vectors often allows us state laws and solve problems more succinctly. For example, we could state the [Maxwell-Faraday equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) in co-ordinate form rather than vector form, but we would have to write and solve three longer equations instead of one shorter one.